# Building a Ionic application without backend

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I am lookin for sample application which one doesnt has any backend as a spring, php etc. Clear Ionic with SQL on your phone. E.g. notes, schedulers. Could anyone show me any samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an offline application just to store the data in your phone, you can use [SQLite](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/).

[Ionic 3, Angular 4 and SQLite CRUD Offline Mobile App](https://www.djamware.com/post/59c53a1280aca768e4d2b143/ionic-3-angular-4-and-sqlite-crud-offline-mobile-app)

Answer (score 0):

Use fire base to build youre application.U can follow up below article to get a basic idea on how to start on that

https://www.joshmorony.com/building-a-crud-ionic-2-application-with-firebase-angularfire/

Comment: But firebase need a internet connection.